# Переменная с именем options ведет к "attempt to set slice of associative array"

Tags: shell, zsh

В shell-скрипте назвал переменную options. Скрипт завершается с ошибкой. Если переименовать, ошибки нет. Это зарезервированное имя? Что означает ошибка "попытка присвоить часть ассоциативного массива"?

Так не работает:

```
function mcve() {
    options='';
    echo 'ok';
}

$ mcve
mcve:1: options: attempt to set slice of associative array
```

А так — работает.

```
function mcve() {
    opts='';
    echo 'ok';
}

$ mcve
ok
```

zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)

**UPD.** Согласно `man zshmisc`, зарезервированным это слово не является.

> RESERVED WORDS
>   The  following words are recognized as reserved words when used as the first word of a command unless quoted or disabled using `disable -r`:
>
> `do done esac then elif else fi for case if while function repeat time until select coproc nocorrect foreach end ! [[ { }`

**UPD2.**

До первого вызова функции со строкой `options='';` (которая выдает ошибку):

```
$ declare options
options
```

После вызова функции:

```
$declare options
options=(autolist on printexitvalue off...<20 строк опций>)
```

---

А такой синтаксис проходит без ошибок.

```
function mcve() {
declare options;
options='';
echo ok;
}

$ zsh
$ mcve
ok
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31720858/2790048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, `options` описан как ассоциативный массив.

посмотреть его текущее содержимое можно, например, так:

```
$ declare options
```

судя по его содержимому, именно оно описано в `man zshoptions`.

Comment: т.е. это переменная, объявляемая zsh? как-нибудь можно получить полный список таких переменных?

Comment: *переменная, объявляемая zsh?* — правильнее сказать, наверно, «получившая значение в одном из стартовых скриптов». список объявленных массивов можно получить командой `declare` (без аргументов). список объявлений функций — командой `set` (там перечисляются и переменный окружения, что непосредственно к shell-у отношения не имеет). в дополнение ещё есть программа `env`, возвращающая (без аргументов) список переменных окружения — но это уже не относится непосредственно к shell-у.

Comment: ещё, пожалуй, команду `alias` стоит упомянуть — она выдаёт список определённых в этой сессии shell-а alias-ов.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Похоже, будто значение она получает в момент ошибки. Или я не понимаю чего-то очень важного в объявлении переменных в zsh.

Comment: ну, судя по тому, что изменить содержимое этого массива (мне) zsh не даёт, данный массив, видимо, отнесён разработчиками zsh в разряд «внутренних», а судя по его содержимому, является «отражением» того, что описано в `man zshoptions`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вместо присвоения попробуйте просто получить значение: `echo $options`. по идее, этого достаточно для инициализации содержимого.